Is there a difference between a "load switch" and a "mosfet driver"?
I'd like to use the proper term when talking to fellow EE.
Is a load switch simply a MOSFETs half-bridge driver?

Yes, there is a difference.
A load switch is specifically designed to be used to switch power to a load. It is always a single MOSFET, not a half-bridge, and almost always positioned on the high side. Most load switches have the FET integrated; some are nothing but a MOSFET. They usually use P-channel devices, because using an N-channel one would require boosting the input voltage somehow. Many load switches include monitoring or protection circuitry, like a power-good output or an overcurrent detector. They aren't designed to switch quickly, because you don't typically turn them on and off frequently. The MOSFET is typically optimized for very low on resistance at the expense of input capacitance and gate charge.
A MOSFET driver, on the other hand, is a push-pull level shifter designed to output high-current pulses to quickly charge and discharge a MOSFET or IGBT's gate capacitance. They're designed to switch on and off rapidly, some at rates of up to a few megahertz for switching converters. They are not usually designed to output continuous current, and definitely can't output their full peak current continuously. Unlike a load switch, which simply disconnects the load when turned off, leaving it floating, a driver actively drives the load to ground. Some of them are isolated for use on high-side MOSFETs, and some are designed as half-bridge drivers to drive both high- and low-side MOSFETs. Some high-side drivers and many half-bridge drivers have a pin for connecting a bootstrap circuit, a capacitor and diode used as a charge pump to provide a drive voltage for the high-side MOSFET.
A MOSFET driver in conjunction with a suitable MOSFET could be used as a load switch, but you'd lack a lot of the extra features load switches can have.
In short, a load switch is optimized to be used like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
And a gate driver is designed to be used like this:

simulate this circuit
As you can see, the two applications are very different.

Wonderfull answer. Thank you so much.
